# Initiating product consumption android in app billing

Tags: android, in-app-billing

For testing i want to initiate consume request on a speciffic products.

I know that it can be done using:

```
public void consumeItem() {
    mHelper.queryInventoryAsync(mReceivedInventoryListener);
}

IabHelper.QueryInventoryFinishedListener mReceivedInventoryListener = new IabHelper.QueryInventoryFinishedListener() {
       public void onQueryInventoryFinished(IabResult result,
          Inventory inventory) {

          if (result.isFailure()) 
          {
              ShowToast("There seem to be a problem completing the process, Please try later",Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
          } 
          else 
          {
                 mHelper.consumeAsync(inventory.getPurchase(current_productid), mConsumeFinishedListener);
          }
    }
};
```

But when i try this i get:

> 04-02 21:32:33.586: E/IabHelper(16254): In-app billing error: Illegal state for operation (queryInventory): IAB helper is not set up.

So how can i do this?